# Objective-C array issues

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have this NSArray and each item returns a POIndex and PONumber and I am putting each item of the array inside another Array and the other array is returning like this:

```
POIndex
PONumber
POIndex
PONumber
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void)GetRequest
{

    NSArray *tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetPurchaseOrderItems:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",areaPickerSelectionString,unitPickerSelectionString]];

    if(!self.objects){
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < [tableData count]; i++){
        [self.objects addObjectsFromArray:[tableData objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Here is a screenshot of what tableData is returning:

[image]

What I am looking to do is have have the PONumber as the key and POIndex as the display value, how would I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *subDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in tableData) {
        [subDict setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"POIndex"] forKey:[dict objectForKey:@"PONumber"]];
        [self.objects addObject:subDict];
    }
```

but this displays like so:

```
{
{
{
{
```

Here is what is displaying it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you want key/value pairs then you want a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tableData array contains NSDictionary at each index. So you can use the same array in your cellForRowIndexPath method like as follows,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray * tableData;

- (void)GetRequest
{
   self.tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetPurchaseOrderItems:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",areaPickerSelectionString,unitPickerSelectionString]];

   [self.yourTableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSString *strPOIndex = [self.tableData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"POIndex"];
   cell.textLabel.text = strPOIndex;
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'TableData'

Comment: This works...but when I have this code in there...why?: `
    if(!self.objects){
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    
    NSMutableDictionary *subDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in _tableData) {
        [subDict setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"POIndex"] forKey:[dict objectForKey:@"PONumber"]];
        [self.objects addObject:subDict];
    }
`